# Can I install MySQL and SQL Server Express edition on Azure Standard website package?

Tags: azure

I am planning to go for Azure with Standard package for websites (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=web#) Which gives much more facility which I am looking for, except 1 i.e. database support.

My question is, Can I use Azure website standard package to host my websites and connect remotely to this machine to install MySql or SQL Server express on virtual machine ?

Or

Should I go with extra small virtual machine and install IIS + MySQL + SQL Server Express and deploy my sites? but in this case can I get features provided for websites from Azure ?

Comment: This should be asked on SuperUser, since it's not a programming question. Also: There is no *standard package* to go for with Azure. You can use any and all services at any time.

Answer (score 4):

No.
When using Windows Azure [WebSites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/web-sites/) (as opposed to [Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/virtual-machines/) or [Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/cloud-services/)) the container is IIS as opposed to a Virtual Machine.

Whilst it is true that on the 'standard' tier you get dedicated instances which does translate to dedicated virtual machines, you do not have access to these virtual machines and cannot install anything on them.

To be able to do that you should look at either  [Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/virtual-machines/) or [Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/cloud-services/)